# what is mean by swift condition is if ((status & 0x3F) == 1 ){ }

Tags: swift

if ((status & 0x3F) == 1 ){ }..
 the status is variable in swift language.
 what is mean about this condition, & mean and (status & 0x3F) value return

Comment: if( (dtc24_state[2] & 0x1) == 0x1 )
                {  }
                else if( (dtc24_state[2] & 0x2) == 0x2 )
                {
                }

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the *bitwise AND* operator.  It compares the bits of the two operands and sets the corresponding bit to `1` if it is `1` in both operands, or to `0` if either or both are `0`.

So this statement:

```
((status & 0x3F) == 1)
```

is combining `status` with `0b111111` (the binary equivalent of `0x3F` and checking if the result is exactly `1`.  This will only be true if the last 6 bits of `status` are `0b000001`.

---

In this `if`:

```
if( (dtc24_state[2] & 0x8) == 0x8 ) {
    self.haldexABCDTC24State.text = status_str + " - UNKNOWN"
    self.haldexABCDTC24State.textColor = text_color
    active_or_stored_dtc = true
}
```

`dct24_state` is an array of values.  The value of `dct24_state[2]` is combined with `0x8` or `0b1000` and checked against `0x8`.  This is checking if the 4th bit from the right is set.  Nothing else matters.  If the 4th bit from the right is set, the `if` is true and the code block is executed.

Comment: if( (dtc24_state[2] & 0x8) == 0x8 )
                {
                    self.haldexABCDTC24State.text = status_str + " - UNKNOWN";
                    self.haldexABCDTC24State.textColor = text_color
                    active_or_stored_dtc = true
                }
is a condition  what is mean

Answer (score 0):

0x3F is `111111`. So, it means this:

for each bit of yourNumber in binary system presentation use `and` method. 
This way truncates the left part of the number. and the result compares with `1`.

e.g.

`7777` is `1111001100001` after executing `and` this number converts into

`100001`. So the result is `false`.

But for `7745` (`1111001000001`) the result is `1`. The result is `true`.

The rule for 'and' function: `0 & 0 = 0 ; 0 & 1 = 0; 1 & 0 = 1; 1 & 1 = 1.`